# How to read chunked http response in ESP32

Tags: http, arduino, esp32

Basically I want to develop code for sending a GET request to an API using ESP32 (Arduino framework).
However the HTTP response is going to be very large (JSON object), hence I have used the transfer encoding: chunked
header. My question is how to read and process the chunked response, the below code gives an the following
error:

```
Connecting to WiFi..
Connected to the WiFi network
-11
Error on HTTP request
-11
```

This error does not occour if the header is not added

```
    #include<Arduino.h>
    #include <WiFi.h>
    #include <HTTPClient.h>
    
    const char* ssid = ""; // my access point 
    const char* password =  ""; //my password
    const String URL = ""; //the api url
    
        
    void setup() {
     
      Serial.begin(115200);
      delay(4000);
      WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
     
      while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(1000);
        Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
      }
     
      Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");
      //sw.begin(115200);
     
    }
     
    void loop() {
     
      if ((WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)) { //Check the current connection status
     
        HTTPClient http;
     
        http.begin(URL); //Specify the URL
        http.addHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "Chunked");    // for getting chunked data
        
        int httpCode = http.GET();                                        //Make the request
     
        if (httpCode > 0) { //Check for the returning code
            String payload = http.getString();
            Serial.println(httpCode);
            Serial.println(payload);
          }
     
        else {
          Serial.println(httpCode);
          Serial.println("Error on HTTP request");
        }
     
        http.end(); 
      }
     
      delay(10000);
     
    }
```

Comment: When you say "the below code gives an HTTP error.", please also include the console output with the error code and relevant context.

Comment: Have added both please check

Answer (score 0):

Two years later but just in case someone finds my comment useful ...
If after adding some code you receive a -11 (which means a Timeout has occurred) then probably that piece added makes the request fail and no response is returned from the server.